# What's the most efficient way to handle quota for the YouTube Data API when developing a chat bot?

Tags: youtube-api, chatbot, quota

I'm currently developing a chat bot for one specific YouTube channel, which can already fetch messages from the currently active livechat. However I noticed my quota usage shooting up, so I took the "liberty" to calculate my quota cost.

My API call currently looks like this `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=some_livechat_id&part=snippet,authorDetails&pageToken=pageTokenIfProvided`, which uses up 5 units. I checked this by running one API call and comparing the quota usage before and after (so apologies, if this is inaccurate). The response contains `pollingIntervalMillis` set to `5086` milliseconds. Currently, my bot adds that interval to the current datetime and schedules the next fetch at that time (using Celery), so it currently fetches messages at a rate of 4-6 seconds. I'm gonna take the liberty and always wait for 6 seconds.

Calculating my API quota would result in a usage of 72.000 units per day:

```
10 requests per minute * 60 minutes * 24 hours = 14.400 requests per day
14.400 requests * 5 units per request = 72.000 units per day
```

This means that if I used the `pollingIntervalMillis` as a guideline for how often to request, I'd easily reach the maximum quota of 10.000 units by running the bot for 3 hours and 20 minutes. In order to not use up the quota by just fetching chat messages, I would need to run 1 API call per minute (1,3889 approximately). This is very unfeasible for a chatbot, since this is only for fetching messages and not even sending any messages to the chat.

So my question is: **Is there maybe a more efficient way to fetch chat messages which won't use up the quota so much? Or will I only get this resolved by applying for a quota extension? And if this is only resolved by a quota extension, how much would I need to ask for reliably? Around 100k units? Even more?**

I am also asking myself how something like Streamlabs Chatbot (previously known as AnkhBot) accomplishes this without hitting the quota limit despite thousands of users using their API client, their quota must probably be in the millions or billions.

And another question would be how I'd actually fill out the form, if the bot is still in this "early" state of development?

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much hit the nail on the head. Services like Streamlabs are owned by larger companies, in their case Logitech. They not only have the money to throw around for things like increasing their API quota, but they also have professional relationships with companies like Google to decrease their per unit cost.

As for efficiency, the API costs are easily found in the documentation, but for live chat as you've found, you're going to be hitting the API for 5 units per hit. The only way to improve your overall daily cost with your calls is to perform them less frequently. While once per minute is clearly excessively long, once every 15-18 seconds could reduce the overall cost of your API quota increase, while making the chat bot adequately responsive.

Of course that all depends on your desired usage of the data, but still a recommendation if you're implementing the bot still in the realm of hobbyist usage.